# opening code generated pdf in browser without saving it to either webserver/client

Tags: vb.net, pdf

Is this even possible? tried several ways and i have no idea how to continue.
Using vb.net in vs 2008 and itextsharp

This is my code for creating the pdf.. also have alot of code to fill it

```
    Dim doc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 90, 80, 80, 90)
    Try

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(Server.MapPath("PDF.pdf"),FileMode.Create))
```

But this saves the pdf.. can i do it any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I use a MemoryStream to assemble the PDF into thus (sorry in C# but should be easily convertable):

```
public byte[] GetPDF()
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 38f, 30f, 15f, 35f);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
        ...
        document.Close();
        return (ms.GetBuffer());
    }
}
```

Then you can provide a byte stream back to your response stream, in MVC I do this with a FileResult return as follows:

```
return File(GetPDF(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "generated.pdf");
```